# Tkinter Toplevel not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I'm trying to build a tkinter program that will take a search string from a text field on a main window, then create a child window with the results of the search string. Since I'm new tkinter I'm just trying to get the child window created and have the search string passed to that window for now.  When running my program I receive the error:

```
AttributeError: '_tkinter.tkapp' object has no attribute 'Toplevel'
```

regarding line:

```
line 23, in search
```

which is:

```
results_window = self.parent.Toplevel(self)
```

Here is the code:

```
import tkinter as tk

#App Constants
APP_TITLE = 'TKINTER_TEST'
APP_ICON = '\icon\path.ico'

#Geo Constants
MAIN_WIDTH = 600
MAIN_HEIGHT = 300
MAIN_X = '-0'
MAIN_Y = '+0'


class MainApp():
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent

    def get_search(self):
        pass

    def search(self, search_string):
        results_window = self.parent.Toplevel(self)


    def build_widgets(self):
        search_string = tk.StringVar()
        text = tk.Entry(root, textvariable = search_string).pack()
        search_cmd = tk.Button(root, text="Search", command=self.search(search_string.get())).pack()


#MAIN
root = tk.Tk()

#root.geometry('500x300-0+0')
root.geometry('{}x{}{}{}'.format(MAIN_WIDTH, MAIN_HEIGHT, MAIN_X, MAIN_Y))
root.title(APP_TITLE)

main = MainApp(root)
main.build_widgets()

root.mainloop()
```

Am I approaching this the wrong way?

Comment: There are a few things you can do to improve the structure of that code, but to answer your immediate question, you create a `Toplevel` window just like you create a widget, eg `results_window = tk.Toplevel(root)` or `results_window = tk.Toplevel(self.parent)`. BTW, your widgets probably should use the `self.parent` rather than the global `root`. It doesn't hurt to use `root`, but it's neater if the GUI object uses its own attributes rather than referring to a global name like `root`.

Comment: @PM2Ring, thank you very much!  That worked perfectly.  I also fixed my references to root, changing them to self.parent.  That is much better.  When you mentioned that there were a few things I could do to improve the structure of the code, may I ask for an example of what you meant?  I'd like for it to be as professional as possible so that I can get in the habit of that now so that it comes natural in future projects.

Comment: Sorry, I'm busy with my own code right now, which is why I didn't write a proper answer. But you could put the `root = tk.Tk()` and related code into the `__init__` of  `MainApp`.

Answer (score 0):

`Toplevel` is a widget like e.g. `Frame`

So the line 23 must be :
`self.result_window = tk.Toplevel(self.parent)`